# How to program a textbox so that multiple values are separated by quotes?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Good morning everyone!

I am experimenting with an Access 2007 form which contains a textbox that inserts values into a query. I want to be able to enter multiple values into the textbox. The values are separated by a comma but are also wrapped in quotes. The values in the textbox are inserted in a HAVING Clause.

Here is what the code looks like:

Example:

```
HAVING Max([COLOR].[COLOR_CODE] In ("11111","22222"))
```

Now I want to use a textbox on a form to insert the value but I need to handle the quotes. So I converted the values to Numbers both at the SELECT Statement and at the HAVING Clause.

Example:

```
HAVING Max(CLng([COLOR].[COLOR_CODE] In ([Forms].[MyForm]![txtColorCode])))
```

The problem is when I enter 11111 into the textbox on the form the query works but when I enter 11111,22222 the query does not work.

So I have this idea; what if I could enter, e.g:  `11111,22222,33333,44444` and  use code to format the values to `"11111","22222","33333","44444"`

This way I can abandon the Conversion/CLng and just use the IN Operator with the string.

How can I formatting or transformation so that it is inserted into the query. Maybe on Submit?

I would really appreciate and input or ideas.

Thanks everyone.

Guy

Answer (score 0):

Where are these values coming from? Is a listbox out of the question? Do not forget that you can add and delete values from a list box easily enough and even more easily if you can reference a table. Once you have the values selected, you can iterate over them to create the clause you need.

You will always have to build the query in VBA, you will not be able to refer to a textbox like this in the query design window.

Comment: Good morning, basically, the user enters values into a text box. Example: Enter ColorCodes: and the user can enter multiple codes separated by comma. E.g. 11111,22222. I cannot use a list box because the user may have only one code or multiple codes. Also the numbers I am using are examples, they are usually not in sequence like that.

Comment: A list box accepts a value list. You will have to build this query in VBA, if the values entered are numbers, they should not be quoted. If they need to be quoted, you can do this when you are building the query ( approx. `Replace(MyString,",","','")` ) This would be easier to control with a listbox.